# How do I print a list of strings on multiple lines? How do I prevent my program from exiting early?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am coding up a project that asks users to fill in seats for a 10-passenger plane. I have the entire thing coded, and it runs the way I want it to, however there are two small details that i am unable to troubleshoot on my own. The first being that the plane can hold up to 10 passengers. I used a list of strings to be able to hold all the different passengers. However, because of the way I set it up, once the 10th passenger is inputted the program exits due to the way I set up my code. (I'm sure using loops would have been easier, but I didn't know how to do that). Once you see the code below, you'll see what I mean. After the 10th passenger is inputted I should be able to run all the display screen options.

Secondly, I need to be able to display the passenger list as a vertical display list, however every time I try to break up my list of strings using \n it displays as every letter on a new line. The output should look like:
Passenger #1 = Name
Passenger #2 = Name
and so on

However, mine displays as Passenger #1 = Name Passenger #2 = Name and so on.

Any help fixing these problems would be appreciated.

```
# Seating List

Seating_Chart = ["Seat #1 = Empty", "Seat #2 = Empty", "Seat #3 = Empty", "Seat #4 = Empty", "Seat #5 = Empty", "Seat #6 = Empty", "Seat #7 = Empty", "Seat #8 = Empty", "Seat #9 = Empty", "Seat #10 = Empty"]
Seating_Chart = ' '.join(Seating_Chart)

# Display Menu

Display_Menu = """1. Assign Seat.
2. Print Seat Map.
3. Print Boarding Pass.
-1. Quit"""
print(Display_Menu)
print()

# Gets User Input

User_Input = input("")

# If/Else Statements
while User_Input != "-1":
    if User_Input == "1":
        name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
        Seating_Chart = Seating_Chart.replace("Empty", name, 1)
        Split_List = Seating_Chart.split(" ")
        if "Empty" not in Seating_Chart:
            print("Next flight leaves in 3 hours.")
        print()
    elif User_Input == "2":
        print("***************************************")
        print(Seating_Chart)
        print("***************************************")
        print()
    elif User_Input == "3":
        print("""Type 1 to get Boarding Pass by Seat Number
Type 2 to get Boarding Pass by name""")
        print()
        User_Choice = input("")
        while User_Choice != "1" and User_Choice != "2":
            User_Choice = input("""Type 1 to get Boarding Pass by Seat Number
Type 2 to get Boarding Pass by name""")
            print()
        if User_Choice == "1":
            Seat_Number = int(input("What is the seat number: "))
            if Seat_Number > 10:
                print("Invalid number--no boarding pass found")
            print()
            print("======= Boarding Pass =======")
            print("     Seat #:", Seat_Number)
            print("     Passenger Name:", Split_List[((Seat_Number * 4) - 1)])
            print("=============================")
            print()
        elif User_Choice == "2":
            Passenger_Name = input("Enter passenger name: ")
            if Passenger_Name in Split_List:
                print(Split_List)
                Passenger_Name_Index = Split_List.index(Passenger_Name)
                print(Passenger_Name_Index)
                Passenger_Name_Method_Two = Split_List[Passenger_Name_Index]
                Seat_Index = Passenger_Name_Index - 2
                if Seat_Index >= 0 and Seat_Index <= 3:
                    Printed_Seat = 1
                elif Seat_Index >= 4 and Seat_Index <= 7:
                    Printed_Seat = 2
                elif Seat_Index >= 8 and Seat_Index <= 11:
                    Printed_Seat = 3
                elif Seat_Index >= 12 and Seat_Index <= 15:
                    Printed_Seat = 4
                elif Seat_Index >= 16 and Seat_Index <= 19:
                    Printed_Seat = 5
                elif Seat_Index >= 20 and Seat_Index <= 23:
                    Printed_Seat = 6
                elif Seat_Index >= 24 and Seat_Index <= 27:
                    Printed_Seat = 7
                if Seat_Index >= 28 and Seat_Index <= 31:
                    Printed_Seat = 8
                if Seat_Index >= 32 and Seat_Index <= 35:
                    Printed_Seat = 9
                if Seat_Index >= 36 and Seat_Index <= 39:
                    Printed_Seat = 10
                print()
                print("======= Boarding Pass =======")
                print("     Seat #:", Printed_Seat)
                print("     Passenger Name:", Passenger_Name_Method_Two)
                print("=============================")
                print()
            else:
                print("No passenger with that information could be found.")
    print(Display_Menu)
    User_Input = input("")
if User_Input == "-1":
    print("Have a nice day!")
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't exit after the 10th passenger! I was able to input more names (without affecting the list) and to test further options.

Comment: Also, an easy fix to your second problem is to put the `\n` directly in the declaration of the `Seating_Chart`. Since you don't need to print it in any other way (that would mean fixes in the last sections).

Comment: If you use a list of names for `Seating_Chart`, that would be easier. Put all the "Seat #X" stuff in the printing, not directly in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please, see the below solution
you can use the counter to count the number of passengers and add the validation.
2) you can split the list and add new lines.

```
Seating_Chart = ["Seat #1 = Empty", "Seat #2 = Empty", "Seat #3 = Empty", "Seat #4 = Empty", "Seat #5 = Empty", "Seat #6 = Empty", "Seat #7 = Empty", "Seat #8 = Empty", "Seat #9 = Empty", "Seat #10 = Empty"]
Seating_Chart = ' '.join(Seating_Chart)

# Display Menu

Display_Menu = """1. Assign Seat.
2. Print Seat Map.
3. Print Boarding Pass.
-1. Quit"""
print(Display_Menu)
print()

# Gets User Input

User_Input = input("")
count = 0
# If/Else Statements
while User_Input != "-1":
    if User_Input == "1":
        count = count + 1

        if (count <=10):
            name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
            Seating_Chart = Seating_Chart.replace("Empty", name, 1)
            Split_List = Seating_Chart.split(" ")
            if "Empty" not in Seating_Chart:
                print("Next flight leaves in 3 hours.")
            print()
        else:
            print("The plane cannot hold more passengers.")
    elif User_Input == "2":
        print("***************************************")

        for item in Seating_Chart.split("Seat #"):
            if (str(item)!=""):
                print ("Seat #"+str(item))


        print("***************************************")
        print()
    elif User_Input == "3":
        print("""Type 1 to get Boarding Pass by Seat Number
Type 2 to get Boarding Pass by name""")
        print()
        User_Choice = input("")
        while User_Choice != "1" and User_Choice != "2":
            User_Choice = input("""Type 1 to get Boarding Pass by Seat Number
Type 2 to get Boarding Pass by name""")
            print()
        if User_Choice == "1":
            Seat_Number = int(input("What is the seat number: "))
            if Seat_Number > 10:
                print("Invalid number--no boarding pass found")
            print()
            print("======= Boarding Pass =======")
            print("     Seat #:", Seat_Number)
            print("     Passenger Name:", Split_List[((Seat_Number * 4) - 1)])
            print("=============================")
            print()
        elif User_Choice == "2":
            Passenger_Name = input("Enter passenger name: ")
            if Passenger_Name in Split_List:
                print(Split_List)
                Passenger_Name_Index = Split_List.index(Passenger_Name)
                print(Passenger_Name_Index)
                Passenger_Name_Method_Two = Split_List[Passenger_Name_Index]
                Seat_Index = Passenger_Name_Index - 2
                if Seat_Index >= 0 and Seat_Index <= 3:
                    Printed_Seat = 1
                elif Seat_Index >= 4 and Seat_Index <= 7:
                    Printed_Seat = 2
                elif Seat_Index >= 8 and Seat_Index <= 11:
                    Printed_Seat = 3
                elif Seat_Index >= 12 and Seat_Index <= 15:
                    Printed_Seat = 4
                elif Seat_Index >= 16 and Seat_Index <= 19:
                    Printed_Seat = 5
                elif Seat_Index >= 20 and Seat_Index <= 23:
                    Printed_Seat = 6
                elif Seat_Index >= 24 and Seat_Index <= 27:
                    Printed_Seat = 7
                if Seat_Index >= 28 and Seat_Index <= 31:
                    Printed_Seat = 8
                if Seat_Index >= 32 and Seat_Index <= 35:
                    Printed_Seat = 9
                if Seat_Index >= 36 and Seat_Index <= 39:
                    Printed_Seat = 10
                print()
                print("======= Boarding Pass =======")
                print("     Seat #:", Printed_Seat)
                print("     Passenger Name:", Passenger_Name_Method_Two)
                print("=============================")
                print()
            else:
                print("No passenger with that information could be found.")
    print(Display_Menu)
    User_Input = input("")
if User_Input == "-1":
    print("Have a nice day!")
```